# Reading values from xls file in golang on linux system

Tags: linux, go, ubuntu-14.04, xls

I am writing a program to read xls file in Go. I am using the `github.com/extrame/xls` package.
I want to read each cell if it is not empty. (Note some rows will have values in all 11 columns but some will not.)

My code is:

```
if xlFile, err := Open("Table.xls", "utf-8"); err == nil {
    if sheet1 := xlFile.GetSheet(0); sheet1 != nil {
        fmt.Print("Total Lines ", sheet1.MaxRow, sheet1.Name)
        col1 := sheet1.Rows[0].Cols[0]
        col2 := sheet1.Rows[0].Cols[0]
        for i := 0; i <= (int(sheet1.MaxRow)); i++ {
            row1 := sheet1.Rows[uint16(i)]
            col1 = row1.Cols[0]
            col2 = row1.Cols[11]
            fmt.Print("\n", col1.String(xlFile), ",", col2.String(xlFile))
        }
    }
}
```

It gives the following error:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
```

Because the cell 11 is empty for some rows.

Please advise a better method or a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking the repo you are mentioning there is a `row.go` file where is defined the `Row` struct as the following:

```
type Row struct {
    info *RowInfo
    Cols map[uint16]contentHandler
}
```

This contains the `Cols` map which keys are `uint16` values. Because in go you can verify if a map key exists in the following way:

```
if col2, ok := row1.Cols[11]; ok { }
```

this means you can test if the cells are not empty by checking if they contains a key.

```
if col2, ok := row1.Cols[11]; ok { 
    fmt.Print("\n", col2.String(xlFile))
}
```

Comment: Great that it helped.

Comment: clean answer, helped with mine issue 2

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that if you have empty trailing columns, the Cols slice is only as big as the number of filled out columns.

In this case, just do:

```
if len(row1.Cols) < 12 {
 // Whatever you want to do with < 12 columns 
} else {
 // Use Cols[11] (12th column) here
}
```

If you want just first and last columns, you can do:
`rows1.Cols[0]` and `rows1.Cols[len(row1.Cols)-1]` which will work with arbitrarily wide rows.

You if there might be blank rows, first check for `len(rows1.Cols) == 0` to make sure you don't attempt to access non-existant data.

Comment: will this work if there are empty cell in the middle too? say cell 2 cell 4  can be empty too.
so i want to know if that particular cell is empty

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to check Cols length before you got Cols[11]?

```
if len(row1.Cols) > 10 {
  col2 = row1.Cols[11]
}else{
  col2 = Col{}
}
```

Comment: will this work if there are empty cell in the middle too?

Comment: Yes it will. It can access to `Cols[11]` if only `Cols` have 12 elements or more.